# How to show the normal of a face

Tags: faces, normals

How do you show the normal of a face in Blender 2.8.

It used to be in the properties panel (n to show) but now where has it gone?

Comment: I think this place could do with a 2.8 tag as there will be a lot of questions that relate to the new way of doing things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out

- Expand Overlays (top-right)
- Tick Face Orientation

Now blue faces are one way (presume forward) and red are other (presume backwards)

Answer (score 5):

in overlay option check "Face orientation"

[image]

Comment: that is face orientation. In this picture, "Normals" section is just below the "Measurement" section