# display face normal direction in blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, normals

How can I know if the normals of an object are flipped or not? Because in version 2.8 both normals have the same color and I can't identify if it's a flipped normal, unlike the previous versions where there are two colors of the faces: white is a real object, while light purple is a flipped normal.

Comment: In 2.8 it's different now, to preview normals orientation you have to use Overlays menu and enable preview mode there. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119408/how-to-show-the-normal-of-a-face

Comment: Both methods are available in Blender 2.8x.

Answer (score 16):

Go into edit mode

[image]

Select the overlays drop down and click on the button shown in the picture below

[image]

You will see blue lines in the direction the faces are facing

[image]

Answer (score 14):

An even faster way to quickly check is to check the box that says Face Orientation. It'll color any flipped normals to red from blue.
[image]

Comment: Also in blender@3.2.1 (y)