# Adding clay strips will subtract on certain surfaces of a face that I am modeling

Tags: sculpt

I'm looking at a face I'm modeling from the front (although this is consistent from any angle), when I use the *add clay strips* on the bridge of the nose, if my brush even touches the sides (like the nostrils) the clay strips will subtract, even though it is still set to add.

I could draw a continuous line, left to right, across the face, it will add as it passes over the cheeks, but then as it crosses the sides of the nose the brush will subtract, but then add again as it passes over the bridge of the nose.

I followed the solution steps in a similar question on this site, but no success: I went to the object tab, <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, scale, and then it gives me some options, I made sure scale was checked.

Then I go to *edit*, select all, I have to hit <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open the normals tab (if I hit <kbd>⌃ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, like I'm told, it will ask to open a new file) the normals tab is open and I tried the various options, even the two for recalculating and flipping. Doesn't work.

The images shows that I can add to the cheeks, but side of the nose subtracts and thins out the bridge of the nose
[image: See, I can add to the cheeks, but side of the nose subtracts and thins out the bridge of the nose]
[image: second image]

Comment: I did find a "solution" but I don't think it's great fix. Basically, if I keep adding material to the sides with the subtracting error, it eventually subtracts so much that it starts adding again, so then I remesh, and smooth it out. It's an annoying fix because I can see this solution not helping at all if I am working on many small details - I would basically have to resculpt it everytime it happens.

Comment: It could be a case of normals facing the wrong way. Try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode and select `mesh > normals > recalculate outside` from the menu at the top of the viewport.

Comment: It's Shift N, not Ctrl N, to recalculate normals.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I tried that too, i Icouldn't get it to solve the problem that way, thanks tho

Comment: @joshsanfelici shift N for me creates a new document, it doesn't do anything for normals. Idk why. I just installed it recently so it's in default settings too

Comment: Try *Alt+N* for the Normals menu. The shortcut had changed for Blender 2.8. - Oh, you did that already (edited question).  Maybe check the face orientation with the overlay (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145751/107598). Red is bad.