# Why does it paint on the other side of the object when I'm texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm completely new to blender and I just started texture painting but I'm really confused because every time I try to texture paint on the object the side I'm painting on doesn't have any changes but the opposite side or some other object gets painted?
Also I used the image to paint because I don't know how to paint separate objects
Also am I supposed to send a file on here?

Comment: There's a good quick start guide to texture painting [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjS_zNQNVlw). You can drag and drop images (for instance a screenshot via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu) straight into your question and upload a Blend file via https://pasteall.org/blend/ with a link to it in your question or comment.

Comment: Hello and welcome. In 3D, the faces have a front and a back, and the *normal* determines the sides. There is a [face orientation overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) in Blender to check them.  Your model should be blue (front faces). Red areas are back faces. You only can paint the front faces. If it's flipped the paint will be on the other side of the object. In *Edit* mode you can *Flip* the normals or let Blender *Recalculate (the) Outside* (key A to select all, then Alt+N)

Comment: [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)