# What can I do to remove the black textures around my donut?

Tags: modeling

[image] This only happens when I use cycles as my engine, I tried adding more subsurface or changing the scale but nothing's happening, rendering also shows the same thing, the black textures are on parts where I used the inflate brush.

[image: cycles setting]

[image: plane]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Just from that image, could be overlapping faces, inverted faces or even ngons reacting to the subsuface modifier, you need to describe more of your settings and add more images

Comment: @moonboots thanks for reminding me to upload I am really new to this

Comment: @Emir hello, I tried uploading my cycles render setting, thanks

Comment: What is this "Plane" object in the outliner (right top area of the 1st screenshot)? It's hidden in the viewport ("eye" icon) but still enabled for render ("camera" icon). If it's a backup/old object you can move it into a new collection and deactivate the collection with the checkmark. Everything inside is hidden in the viewport and for render.

Comment: @Blunder hello, the plane object is a plane background for me to see the shadow of the donut, kind of like placing the donut on top of the plane. I uploaded an image with the plane toggled on, thanks :>

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. That looks fine. Have you checked the face orientation? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145751/107598 Everything should be blue. Red faces are flipped and can cause shading issues. (If you want to share your file you have to upload it to a file hoster or google drive because it's most likely too big for blend-exchange.com)