# How to prevent black spot/distortion when creating a new face from verticies?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, normals

Here is the before and after of adding a face to a model of a cabinet. All i did was select four verts and press  <kbd>F</kbd>.

Before
[image: before]

After
[image: after]

Comment: It looks like the newly added face has its normals facing the wrong way, thus causing shading problems. Select the whole object in edit mode and press Shift+N (recalculate normals outside).

Comment: Or do you mean the shading in general? The top image looks like the object is shaded flat, the bottom looks like shaded smooth. Right-click on the object in _Object Mode_ and select _Shade Flat_.

Comment: @ChistopherBennett I tried that and nothing changed. I tried both outside and inside recalculation and flipped to check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display face normal direction in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145751/display-face-normal-direction-in-blender-2-8)