# How do I fix this sharp edge?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to use a loop tools bridge to connect the soles and the toes. But for some reason, there will be an edge than can't apply a subdivision modifier, how can I fix it?[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? (at least this part of your object) https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi! thanks for your question. It looks like it could be an issue caused by irregular face normals, but any extra information you can give could help other users answer your question.

Comment: Looks like flipped normals. Have you checked the [face orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598)?

Comment: Well...check it, you guys are right. Face normals problem, already fixed. Thank you.