# Stencil mode doesn't draw a texture in texture paint?

Tags: texture-painting

Firstly, I imported a ply mesh to Blender 3.3.0 and colored it by attribute.
I selected place in edit mode, where I wanted to draw the texture and created Smart UV Project. [image] Then, I followed by many tutorials and blocked in one moment. I try to draw a texture in stencil mode but it doesn't work in Texture paint interaction mode, but it works on the paint mode.

It's my settings

[image] [image]

Final effect

[image]

Link to blender project:
https://we.tl/t-YinVxn7WUf

Comment: I guess this question is a duplicate. The problem is that you're trying to paint on the backface which doesn't work. If you turn on the *Face Orientation* overlay (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) you will see most of the inside of the room is red. Red=back side, blue=front side. Your 3D scanned(?) mesh is very heavy and I don't know if you can flip the faces easily (there are so many). So it might be easier to just mirror the texture. Set *Brush > Texture > Size X* to `-1` in the Brush/Tool settings. Then paint it from the outside on the wall.

Comment: It works <3 Thanks a lot @Blunder

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question is a duplicate. The problem is that you're trying to paint on the backface which doesn't work. If you turn on the Face Orientation overlay ([display face normal direction in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145751/display-face-normal-direction-in-blender-2-8/216140#216140)) you will see most of the inside of the room is red. Red=back side, blue=front side. Your 3D scanned(?) mesh is very heavy and I don't know if you can flip the faces easily (there are so many). So it might be easier to just mirror the texture. Set *Brush > Texture > Size X* to $-1$ in the *Brush/Tool* settings. Then paint it from the outside on the wall. –
Blunder

In addition, if someone wants to change orientation, you must be in *Edit mode* > *Mesh > Normals* (shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Flip*.