# My model looks ok in Blender but is missing faces in Lychee

Tags: stl

I have a model which looks fine in Blender.  In Lychee, however, parts are missing.  I can only assume something is wrong with my stl export. I have recalculated the normals. Has anyone seen this before?

Lychee:

[image]

Blender:

[image]

Comment: even the blender's recalculate function isn't infallible esspecuially if there are duplicate vetexes and ripped edges. i would recommend doing a visual check of the face normals and merge by distance.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the dup vertices and merged them.  What is a ripped edge?

Comment: A visual check of the normals you can do with the *Face Orientation* overlay (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598). When Lychee uses backface culling then the faces with the flipped normals (red) will not be displayed.