# Shading issue on a line of edges

Tags: modeling, shaders, topology, artifacts

I'm facing an issue with shading on some edges that appear.
Here is a view of the topology.
I make sure it's only quad and that the surface is flat, but still this edge line appear. It's seems that the last line of edges is causing this issue, but I'm not sure why it is causing it. I have try to look for many tutorials online, but haven't find any real solution that worked for me.

[image]
[image]

I have already try many things to correct this issue,
like reinforce edges around the boolean or flat Ngons. It's the closest I could get from not having this shading issue, but still I have some shading issues.
[image]

Do you know if I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome, make sure to check your faces orientation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145751/display-face-normal-direction-in-blender-2-8

Comment: Hello @Emir, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I have checked the face orientation, and everything seems normal on this side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid long thin polygons as they often cause shading issues. Try to make something more like this to minimize the distortion

[image]

[image]

You can see the difference with this part for example

[image]

With you're curent topology, in order to get a clean shading you would have to transfer the normals using a data transfer modifier on the polygons causing distortion, using a cylinder with the same amount of loops as the original cylinder as a source object

[image]

even cleaner than the first method, but make sure you add a triangulate modifier before the data transfer if you plan on exporting the model

[image]

Comment: Hey @Alex, thanks for your response.

So I have tried both methods, the first one with the topology, and it kind of got better, but a similar issue with a triangle was there. But it was less noticeable.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qux.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApK8M.png

The second method was way better with no more lines appearing, but it caused me another issue where other normals were affected by it. I have tried to resmooth the bool part, but the line was reappearing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQAYb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCBYT.png

Comment: @BlenderUser356578 yes, you have to add another loop before the angle so it's not affected by the modifier. If you  look closely on the before last picture, you'll see there is a loop right before the angle

Comment: Indeed it worked the edges are sharp.
I'm still trying to figure out how can I keep the sharpness on those boolean objects without making the artifact reappear https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqlUp.png

Comment: Okay found the solution, it was missing reinforcement as well on the boolean part https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcBSO.jpg
now it's working perfectly fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/teoRl.png. Thank you for the solution :)