# high tris but not smooth surface after subsurface

Tags: mesh

You can see two different models with high vert count good surface on the other hand i have vw model with low quality surface with hight vert count. I need to push subsurface 6.level to good surface but vertex count goes 6million.
[image]
whats the issue
[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
3sub x 2 sub after
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have the RAM to do it, just keep it at 6 million. If not, subdivide at 3, and add another sub-surface, at 2. Could you provide a picture of the high quality model?

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 https://i.stack.imgur.com/p348C.jpg yes now better but 400k is still high

Comment: Have you tried a multires modifier instead?

Comment: no, but now in edit mode it sas 6.9k tris is it true how can i see object tris

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zaXi.png this is still to much verts how the other object has low count and good surface

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). Please [upload your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look. In the meantime, [check your normals orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119408/78972).

Comment: @JachymMichal [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8kBQB4Aq" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8kBQB4Aq/)

Comment: https://free3d.com/tr/3d-model/ac-cobra-269-83668.html this model also low count but good surface

Comment: found the way .. shade smoth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElWn4DAaLbw