# Blender/ Mixamo / clip studio modeler problem : my model is see through?

Tags: modeling

Please take note that I have absolutely no knowledge in blender, my first idea was just creating a simple character model to export it in Mixamo and then register it in Clip Studio Modeler, for a personal art project.

I have this problem for a while now : I created my model in blender, then exported it .fbx for Mixamo, but when the model is completed in Mixamo it is partially see-through ??
I still continued the process and uploaded it in Clip studio modeler : same thing, the model is weird.

Can someone help me ? I think it is a problem with the model in blender, but I never used blender before and im completely lost...

[image]enter image description here
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have flipped faces? When you activate the overlay in Blender then your whole model should be blue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148669/107598

Comment: Oh thanks for the respons ! The head is blue and the body is red... How do I fix that ?

Comment: Oh my god I got it thank you, it was a normal problem , I recalculated normal and that was good !

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't aware that the fix isn't mentioned in the linked question. You need to flip or recalculate the normals (Alt+N in edit mode). Glad you figured it out!