# unable to create hole using mesh->circle while adding vertices(bevel in edit mode) using Boolean modifier difference mode

Tags: modifiers

I'm working where in a project and want to create hole with different styles. So I used circle based mesh (Mesh->Circle then then change vertices number), then in edit mode I beveled the circle(added some vertices so that I got different shape) and created new face (hot key ***F***) and extrude so that have some depth. Now I used normal boolean modifier with difference mode but it not created hole. If I did not modify the circle with bevel it did created hole using same method. The attached picture with green mark circle mesh did not beveled and red marked did beveled. I did many research but did not work. can one help?

[image]

blend file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: boolean shapes]

Two of your "circle" objects have flipped normals. If you [activate the *Face Orientation* overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119408/how-to-show-the-normal-of-a-face) you will see that they are shown in red.

To fix it, go to *Edit* mode, select all <kbd>A</kbd> and flip the normals <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Note: If you use the *Boolean* modifier with the *Solver* option set to `Fast` it will work, too. But it's better to have the normals point outside.

Comment: Did not know about that. Thanks.