# Automatic weights skips vertices

Tags: armature, vertex-weights

I have an object and I added bones to it. It looks like this

[image]

I used automatic weights option to calculate the weights. But some of the vertices are not given a weight. When I move the first bone in pose mode it looks like this

[image]

I have tried removing parent relationship, deleting vertex groups and recalculating weights but the result is the same. I have no idea what could have caused this or how to fix it. Adding those vertices with vertex paint is not something I want to do unless it is the only choice I have so I am asking for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In edit mode, have you checked that the vertices in question are assigned to the correct vertex group?

Comment: @Blunder The said vertices are not in any vertex group

Comment: Ok, that's the reason why this area doesn't move. I guess there is something wrong with the mesh (duplicated vertices, intersecting mesh?) and it causes the [Heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598) error. It cancels the weight paint calculation and can result in such a half-working rig. Can you repeat the step (With Automatic Weights) and check if there is a warning for a few seconds in the status bar as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOFup.gif ?

Comment: @Blunder I have checked the mesh for duplicate vertices and there are no duplicated vertices. Also the object consists of one mesh not more. I ran automatic weights again as you said after deleting vertex groups and no error message showed up.

Comment: darn, it was a good possible reason. Can you share the file?

Comment: @Blunder Sorry for the late answer. Here is the link to the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a8nxWULueEQmDZVDH6VR6KjAKbYrt7jX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the file. That helped to track the error. The mesh of the leg has flipped normals. The whole mesh is basically inside out. You can check this with the Face Orientation overlay (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119408/107598).
That's the reason why the *With Automatic Weights* does not work. Go in *Edit*, select everything with key A, and then flip the normals Alt+N as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167034/107598. (I will mark this question as duplicate)