# Loop cut doesn't work for one part

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

In the first working, but the in the second it is not working

Comment: Because the edge must meet a face that is not a quad but a tri or a ngon, or there is an inner face inside your mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the edge of the waist. There are more vertices than at the shoulder and the pelvis. You probably have duplicated them by mistake.

Merge these vertices so you have a clean edge. The <kbd>M</kbd> key opens the merge menu. Try *Merge At Center*.

The *Merge By Distance* option is useful to remove duplicated vertices that are very close together. Usually, you can't spot these vertices.

Also, check the inside of the model for inner faces and remove them with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces Only*.

Last but not least, check the face orientation/normals: [How to show the normal of a face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119408/107598)

and [How to make all faces flip to the right/consistent direction?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167034/107598) if they are flipped.