# my model transform weirdly

Tags: armature

my models moves very weirdly in pose mode.
I did weight paint in all of the bones (one side and mirrored)
It is not just this leg but happens for the arm too. But it doesn't seem like there's somewhere I painted overly,,,
What should I do?

[link for my model](https://pasteall.org/blend/9b4667de09d54c698e7764f2c40b8d4c)

[image]

[image: link for my object]

Comment: Enter weight paint mode and change to vertex select mode.  Select a vertex that isn't doing what you think it should.  Look on sidebar/item/vertex weights and look for something there that doesn't belong.  Especially, here, look for something with the wrong .L/.R suffix.

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong in vertex weights...

Comment: As Blunder says, recalculating the mesh fixes the problem, you need to reparent though

Answer (score 3):

The mesh of your bunnyman is inside out. The normals are flipped (red). You can check this with the [*Face Orientation* overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119408/107598).

To fix this enter *Edit* mode, then select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for the *Recalculate Outside* command. Now the model should be blue.

Done this, you can bind the mesh to armature with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weights*.

Test pose:
[image: test pose]

Comment: I tried it and It didn't change the problem

Comment: Have you checked the face orientation? Selected the armature last when you use *Parent To*? (Usually, you can't do the order wrong because then the context menu is different.) I've double-checked it and it works for me as you can see above now.

Comment: I did it again and it worked! Thank you